# How do I create a documentFragment in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, dom, gwt

Creating a document fragment using plain Javascript is dead simple: `var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();`.
However, in GWT, this does not appear to be available, though there is a DocumentFragment interface in package com.google.gwt.xml.client that does not appear to be applicable.  Does anyone know of a way, either using the aforementioned interface, or creating a class with a simple JSNI method that creates the documentFragment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a JSNI method returning a DocumentFragment is dead simple.. you just `return document.createDocumentFragment();` :) The JSNI method should either return [`JavaScriptObject`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject.html) or some other type that you know will work (like [`Node`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Node.html) - I'm not sure were you are going with this, but JSOs work that way - you can [`cast<T>()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject.html#cast()) any subclass of `JavaScriptObject` to any other `JavaScriptObject`).

Answer (score 2):

This particular question is addressed (with a workaround similar to Klimer's suggestion) in "[Issue 2955: Not able to create a document fragment object for dom](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2955)" on GWT's issue tracker.

You could also contribute to this ticket and "star" the issue to show your interest in seeing this added to the GWT framework.